# Перевод надписи со старославянского на русский

Tags: переводы

Надпись на надгробной плите предположительно XVIII века:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIxhS.jpg]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это цитата из Нового Завета (Евангелие от Марка 8:34-35) в церковнославянском переводе: «И призвав народы со ученики своими, рече им: иже хощет по мне ити, да отвержется себе, и возмет крест свой, и по мне грядет». В синодальном переводе: «И, подозвав народ с учениками Своими, сказал им: кто хочет идти за Мною, отвергнись себя, и возьми крест свой, и следуй за Мною».

Comment: Благодарю Вас за полный и ясный ответ. И отдельно за быстрый отклик. Всех Вам благ !